# An idiom for "collecting all of the something possible"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm conducting a survey at work, and am looking for an idiom that expresses "not missing any of the ideas that are available"

For some reason, "shake all the apples from the tree" pops into my head, but no amount of googling confirms my latent belief that this in indeed a common phrase.

I guess "scrape the barrel" is related, albeit somewhat pejorative.

Does anyone having something better?

Comment: Perhaps "leave no idea in the corner collecting dust"

Comment: Sounds like you're hoarding!

Comment: Gotta catch ‘em all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say you  ***[leave no stone unturned](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/leave-no-stone-unturned)***:

> If you say that you will leave no stone unturned, you are emphasizing that you will try every way you can think of in order to achieve what you want.

(Collins)

Comment: great, that fits perfectly. Thanks